# Text to excel using TextToColumns, only first record copied

Tags: vba, excel

Newbie in VBA (excel) I am understanding a code that gets the value from a file, but only the first record in the file is transferred to the excel. Code as per below:

```
LineIndex = 0
Erase strLine()
Open myMainFile For Input As #1
   While Not EOF(1)
     LineIndex = LineIndex + 1
     ReDim Preserve strLine(1 To LineIndex)
     Line Input #1, strLine(LineIndex)
     MsgBox strLine(LineIndex)
 Wend
Close #1
.
.
.
With Nw.Worksheets(Mid(FileCol.Cells(i).Value, 7, 4)).Range("A1").Resize     (LineIndex, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strLine)
             .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
             TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone,     ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _              Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False,     Comma:=False, Space:=False 
.
.
.
```

I am having a hard time understanding the second code block, and I believe this is the one causing the error. The file image file is the sample file that I need to transfer to excel

[sample file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKK6R.png)

Excel output of the code is that it only gets the first line of the attached text

Comment: Can you please advise whether your actual code has a line break between `Resize(LineIndex, 1)` and `.Value` - it doesn't make sense without it, so I assume that (and the continuation character in the last line of your posted code) is a problem with how the code was pasted into the question.

Comment: I see `(i)` in your code, this usually indicates a loop. However you don't give `i` a value in your code.